# How to make a reusable SELECT method in OOP php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, class, oop

im new here and im also pretty new to php and OOP so if i dont ask the right question also tell me ;p

im trying to make a class that handles all the queries from and to the database. I want to make this class as reusable as plossible so i dont have to keep writing selects and insert statements in all my methods and functions.

my question is: is it plossible to call on an method with parameters and then have those parameters finish the query for me ?

this is what i had come up with so far:

***Database connection class:***

```
class Database {
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    private $dbname;
  private $charset;

    public function connect() {
    $this->host = 'localhost:3306';
    $this->user = 'root';
    $this->pass = '';
    $this->dbname = 'Testdb';
    $this->charset = 'utf8mb4';

    try {
      $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->dbname.';charset='.$this->charset;
      $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass);
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      return $pdo;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed:".$e->getMessage();
    }

  }
}
```

***this is my query's class:***

```
 class QueryDatabase extends Database {


  public function getData($tablename, $selector, $value) {

    if (!isset($selector)){
        echo 'Something went wrong!';
    } else if ($selector == ''){
      $stmt = $this->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM $tablename");
      while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){

        return $row;
      }
    }else {
      $stmt = $this->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM $tablename where $selector = $value");
      while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){

        return $row;
      }
    }
    }


  public function setData($tablename, $colums, $data) {
    if (!isset($tablename) or !isset($data)) {
      echo 'Something went wrong!';
    } else {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO $tablename ($colums) VALUES ($data)";
      $q = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
      $q->execute();


    }

  }
  protected function addData() {

  }
  protected function delData() {

  }
}
```

***and this is what i mean with the parameters for example:***

```
$test = new QueryDatabase;
  $test->setData('contact_form_messages', 'u_id, name, email, subject, message, date', ' , Kees, Kees@gmail.com, Test, Hopefully it works, ');



i get this error message :


Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' Kees, Kees@gmail.com, Test, Hopelijk werkt hij, )' at line 1 in D:\webProjects\project\classes\querydatabase.class.php:31 
Stack trace: #0 D:\webProjects\project\classes\querydatabase.class.php(31): PDOStatement->execute() #1 D:\webProjects\project\includes\header.inc.php(5):
QueryDatabase->setData('contact_form_me...', 'u_id, name, ema...', ' , Kees, Kees@g...') #2 D:\webProjects\project\contact.php(1): include('D:\\webProjects\\...') #3 {main} thrown in D:\webProjects\project\classes\querydatabase.class.php on line 31

if you have any suggestions i'd be happy to hear them!

thanks a lot!

Floris
```

Comment: You are having a syntax error while executing the query. I suggest you should print out the `$sql` and try the query and execute it on your IDE like Mysql Workbench, so you would see where is the error coming from your query.

Comment: so i printed the sql and this is what it said: 
INSERT INTO contact_form_messages (u_id, name, email, subject, message, date) VALUES ( , Kees, Kees@gmail.com, Test, Hopelijk werkt hij, ) i still dont really get whats wrong. thanks for the tip tho !

Comment: First, you have a mismatch between the fields you are trying to insert and the values you are having. Secondly, you have to add quotation marks `'` around the strings.
So your query should look something like this `INSERT INTO contact_form_messages (u_id, name, email, subject, message, date) VALUES (null, "Kees", "Kees@gmail.com","Test","blahblah","2020-01-01");`
Also you should avoid SQL injection.

Comment: You're missing the values for `u_id` and `date`, and you have no quotes around the string values.

Comment: But you should use a prepared statement with `bindValue()` rather than substituting variables into the SQL.

Comment: first of all thanks Long, it worked! second, Barmar how would you suggest i translate the string of parameters to single values to bind ? i wouldnt know how to attack that.

Comment: Instead of a string argument like `'u_id, name, email, subject, message, date'`, pass an array like `['u_id', 'name', 'email', ...]` instead..